# Switch between two subject lines with a fall back for each if there is no first name

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript

When I want to display between two subject lines it works fine but when I need to add a fall back if there is no first name it stops working.

This works to display a subject line depending on what state is in the data:

```
 <!--%%[
var @FirstName, @subjectline, @salutation, 

set @Email = Lowercase([Email]) 
set @FirstName = ProperCase([FirstName])
set @State = [State]

       if @State == "NSW" then
  set @subjectline = Concat(@firstname,", have you reviewed your strata proposal?")
elseif @State == "VIC" or @State == "QLD" then
  set @subjectline= Concat(@firstname,", have you reviewed your body corporate proposal")
endif

]%%
 -->
```

This isn't working:

```
if @State == "NSW" then
    if Empty(@FirstName) or IsNull(@FirstName) then
        set @subjectline = "Have you reviewed your strata proposal?"
    else
        set @subjectline = Concat(@FirstName,", have you reviewed your strata proposal?")
         endif

 if @State == "VIC" or @State == "QLD" then
    if Empty(@FirstName) or IsNull(@FirstName) then
         set @subjectline = "Have you reviewed your body corporate proposal?"
    else
         set @subjectline = Concat(@FirstName,", Have you reviewed your body corporate proposal?")
    endif
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have opened both `@State` if statements twice, but only closed them once.

I would simplify your code to control expression evaluation using parentheses. Here's some working code:

```js
%%[
var @FirstName, @subjectline, @salutation

set @Email = Lowercase(Email) 
set @FirstName = ProperCase(FirstName)
set @State = State

if @State == "NSW" and (Empty(@FirstName) or IsNull(@FirstName)) then
   set @subjectline = "Have you reviewed your strata proposal?"
elseif @State == "NSW" then
   set @subjectline = Concat(@FirstName,", have you reviewed your strata proposal?")
elseif (@State == "VIC" or @State == "QLD") and (Empty(@FirstName) or IsNull(@FirstName)) then
   set @subjectline = "Have you reviewed your body corporate proposal?"
elseif (@State == "VIC" or @State == "QLD") then
   set @subjectline = Concat(@FirstName,", Have you reviewed your body corporate proposal?")
else
   RaiseError('empty subject line')
endif

]%%
```

Note that you only need to wrap attributes in [square brackets] if the attribute name contains a space or hyphen character.

Comment: That's good to hear. Please could you [accept my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for the benefit of others, and (optionally) feel free to upvote it, if you found it to be helpful.

Comment: Hi -  the error went away and it appeared to be working but I am noticing now that it is only pulling in @state "VIC" and "QLD". "NSW" is not pulling in at all.

Comment: For @State "NSW" it is pulling in the "VIC" and "QLD" subject line

Comment: Hello @Michaelsyd, I've spotted an issue with my conditional logic which would be causing the behaviour you report. I've updated my answer with code that should work.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it! I appreciate your help as I have spent two hours on this!

Comment: @EliotHarper - just being curious.. if I have a variable set to "" then the Empty() will return true, but in which cases will the IsNull() return true? Thanks

Comment: IsNull is actually redundant here, as when using the Empty function, If the expression evaluates as null or empty, the function will output true. IsNull effectively does the same thing, but will only work with DE fields.